# How to find the diffrence between two timestamp & return in standard format

Tags: php, html

I want to find the day or month or year difference between two given time stamp and return it in standard format. i have tried this,

```
function cncunix($stamp)
{
   $date = new DateTime("@$stamp");
   echo $date->format('d') . "\n";    
}

// function to convert timestamp
$m = time()+60*60*24;
$n = time();
$y =  $m - $n;
cncunix($y);
```

Comment: Can you add examples?

Comment: like say i have timestamp for 1 day that is  86400 and another 172800 that is 2 day. what i want is the diffrence shown like " The diifrence is 2 days "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$time_a = 86400;
$time_b = 172800;

$total = $time_b - $time_a;

$days = floor($total/86400);

echo "The difference is $days day(s)"
```

$days will give you the number of days rounded down. For example 2.5 will become 2. If you don't want that then remove floor function.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using standart php func ?

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as this:

```
<?php

$m = time()+60*60*24;
$n = time();

$a = new DateTime();
$a->setTimestamp($m);
$b = new DateTime();
$b->setTimestamp($n);

echo $diff = $a->diff($b)->format("%a");
```

Here is [Eval](https://eval.in/568423)